# Java. How to prevent assigning a method reference to functional interface type argument?

Tags: java, method-reference, functional-interface

Beginning with Java SE 8, if the formal parameter of a method is a functional interface, the argument can be either an object implementing that interface or a reference to some method. It means that the argument can also be a reference to a method that is not logically related to the interface's purpose. Is it possible to force the argument to be only an object implementing the interface, but not to be a method reference? Although it is possible to make the interface non-functional by adding a second abstract method, that additional method nevertheless should be implemented. Is there another way?

Comment: No, not possible.

Comment: In theory interfaces marked with `@FunctionalInterface` should be used for lambdas, but there is nothing that prevents using them anyway. So your only option is not using `@FunctionalInterface` and a good documentation.

Comment: What makes you confident that “an object implementing the interface” does not delegate to the method “not logically related to the interface's purpose”?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to force the argument to be only an object implementing the interface, but not to be a method reference?

There is not.

> Although it is possible to make the interface non-functional by adding a second abstract method, that additional method nevertheless should be implemented. Is there another way?

Indeed, that's the downside of doing that. You can't provide a `default` implementation, as an interface that has exactly 1 non-defaulted method is considered a FunctionalInterface, and you can't decree it to be not so.

What you *can* do, however, is turn that interface into an abstract class, which aren't eligible for being supplied in lambda/methodref form.

More generally, don't fight java features. If someone uses a method ref, they know what they are doing. Or they don't, but if they are just stumbling about without a clue, *trust me*, you can't stop an idiot from ruining a code base by designing good APIs and adding every linter rule you manage to scrounge together. Idiots are *far* too inventive to be stopped by mere mortals.

Comment: Thanks for answering. In C#, a programmer is sometimes faced with the choice between using delegates (which work like function references) and using function objects. It looks like in Java the two concepts were merged into one.

Comment: @rzwitserloot   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76704019/interface-method-reference-to-a-functional-interface    can you check my question ?