# Interface method reference to a functional interface

Tags: java, spring, jwt, functional-interface, method-reference

I am working with Java Spring framework and JWT - Java Web Tokens. I have below class

```
import java.util.function.Function;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import app.com.javainuse.config.JwtTokenUtil;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User u=new User("javainuse", "$2a$10$slYQmyNdGzTn7ZLBXBChFOC9f6kFjAqPhccnP6DxlWXx2lPk1C3G6",new ArrayList<>());
        UserDetails ud=u;
        
        JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil=new JwtTokenUtil();
        
        String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(ud);
        Test t=new Test();
        System.out.println(t.getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getSubject));

        
    }
    
    public <T> T getClaimFromToken(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
        System.out.println(claims.toString());      
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("javainuse").parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }
}
```

I am not able to understand statement containing this Claims::getSubject in main method. It gets passed to a functional interface Named Function<Claims,T> claimresolver. How does a method reference getSubject without implementation able to return subject from claims object in getClaimFromToken method ? When we pass method reference to a Functional Interface we the method must have body wight ? but Claims is an interface and getSubject does not have a body then how does "claimsResolver.apply(claims);" is able to get subject value ?

Comment: I think this is `delegation`. The instance of `Claims` comes from `getAllClaimsFromToken()`. Therefore, the implementation of `Claims` also comes from `getAllClaimsFromToken()` which was called as `Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("javainuse").parseClaimsJws(token).getBody()`

Comment: need more explanation on this. Is there any example online ? What is it called in java terms ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between method reference Bound Receiver and Unbound Receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914775/difference-between-method-reference-bound-receiver-and-unbound-receiver)

Answer (score 1):

`someInstance.getSubject()` bakes a cake and returns it to you.

`Claims::getSubject` is a recipe for baking cakes.

One *does the thing*. The other doesn't do anything, it merely is a description of *how* to do the thing - whatever you hand it to can do the thing, or not, or do it 10 times - or pass the recipe on to somebody else who is then faced with the same choice. They can do whatever they like:

- Toss the recipe in the garbage (and no cakes ever exist).
- Bake a cake.
- Bake 10,000 cakes.
- Start 100 threads and bake 100 cakes simultaneously.
- Save the recipe for later and bake some cakes tomorrow.

When I write down a recipe for making cake, one of the ingredients I'm going to mention is that you will need fresh water.

That means, to bake a cake, I need fresh water. Or perhaps a tap (something that can make fresh water for me). However, to make a cake **recipe** I do not need fresh water at all. I just need to tell *you* (the one who will be following my recipe to bake that cake): "You will need to obtain some fresh water. Not my problem how you do that!".

In other words, a cake recipe is a recipe that turns fresh water (and some other things) into a cake. It does not explain how to obtain fresh water, nor does a recipe for making cake come wrapped around a bottle of fresh water.

In the same vein, `Claims::getSubject` is a recipe that explains how to turn any instance of a class that implements `Claims` (i.e. a Claims instance) into a String. It does not come with an instance of Claims nor does it explain how to make an instance of Claims. It merely says: IF you have an instance of Claims, this recipe lets you turn that Claims into a String!

`Claims::getSubject` specifically says: Take your claims, call it `c`. Run `c.getSubject()`. Voila, there's your string.

Here, you pass that notion (a recipe for turning claims into strings) to the `getClaimFromToken` method, which apparently knows how to produce an instance of Claims.

That's analogous to me handing you a cake recipe today and you showing up with a cake tomorrow. That implies you managed to obtain some fresh water. I do not know how and I don't really need to care - I get to enjoy some cake!

NB: Obviously `getClaimsFromToken` knows how to make an instance that implements `Claims` from a token, and will then apply your recipe (i.e., call `.getSubject()` on it). But that's just 'guessing' - the point of APIs is that they promise they do X. You don't need to bother with knowing *how* it does it, you just need to bother with knowing *what* it does, and perhaps ascertaining that the library is fit for purpose and it does what its docs say it does.

Comment: I understand that we have to accept that this is how lambda work in this situation. I saw it for the first time and I was looking for a page which describes this situation. Just like for Integer like classes there is concept called autoboxing we need to accept this thing as it is. Do you know any page which describes this method reference type ?

Comment: There are method references. There aren't 'method reference types'. Whenever you write a method reference, from the immediately surrounding context, `javac` __must__ be able to determine which functionalinterface it is an implementation for. If javac cannot, that is a compiler error - because there are no types for functions like this, javac needs to figure out (from context) what type you want and compile accordingly.

Comment: So in this case Java compiler sees that claims object has a same method signature as Claims::subject and not the apply method because it accepts Claims instance ?

Comment: No, `::` is the syntax for 'make a method reference'. It would never 'apply the method'. It sees `Claims::getSubject` and translates that to, more or less, `class $InlineImplementation implements Function<Claims, String> { @Override public String apply(Claims c) { return c.getSubject(); }}` followed by `new $InlineImplementation();` which is the value of that expression.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that the `Claims::getSubject` syntax here is passing a method reference to the `Function` interface, rather than implementing the full lambda expression.

The key to how this works is that `Claims` is an interface that extends the `Claims` interface from the `io.jsonwebtoken` library.

That `io.jsonwebtoken.Claims` interface defines various getter methods like `getSubject()`, `getIssuer()` etc. without providing implementations.

So when we call:

```java
Claims::getSubject
```

We are providing a reference to the `getSubject()` method on the `io.jsonwebtoken.Claims` interface.

Even though the interface doesn't provide an implementation, at runtime the `claims` object will actually be an instance of some class that implements the `io.jsonwebtoken.Claims` interface and provides a concrete implementation of `getSubject()`.

When `claimsResolver.apply(claims)` is called, it will invoke that underlying `getSubject()` method on the `claims` instance, which returns the subject value.

So in summary:

- `Claims::getSubject` provides a reference to the interface method
- The `claims` object provides an implementation of that interface
- So `claimsResolver.apply(claims)` is able to call the implemented `getSubject()` method to return the value

Comment: is there any other example link or concept explanation link you can provide ?

Comment: There is [an example](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces).

Answer (score 0):

I found what it is called in java. It is called unbound non-static method references. Here is a link which explains every type method references and the scenario which I was asking to explain. [Unbound Non static method references](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3453296/get-started-with-method-references-in-java.html#:%7E:text=An%20unbound%20non%2Dstatic%20method,example%20is%20String%3A%3AtoLowerCase%20.)

Comment: Congratulations for finding out. Four of the five [newest questions tagged with `method-reference`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-reference?tab=Newest) are asking the same question. Not to speak of the hundred other questions already answered in the past decade.